# provability of while loop vs for loop

Tags: loops

I have this teacher, he's quite smart (sometimes, haha) he said good programmers try to use `while` loops instead of `for` loops. the reason he gave for this is because `while` loops can be proven, as in, one can completely explain what happens in a `while` loop whereas you can't do that for a `for` loop. he also said something about NASA programmers only using `while` loops and not allowed to do `for` loops because of this.

I have quite a hard time understand this, for both loops one can explain how they work in detail right? for both you would always know what is going to happen?

can someone explain to me why `while` loops can be proven (And because of it, might be better than `for` loops, in some cases at least).

**EDIT:**
maybe he was reffering to:
[2: All loops must have a fixed upper bound. It must be trivially possible for a checking tool to statically prove that a preset upper bound on the number of iterations of a loop cannot be exceeded. If the loop-bound cannot be proven statically, the rule is considered violated.](http://sdtimes.com/nasas-10-rules-developing-safety-critical-code/)

Though this still doesn't say anything about the difference between while and for loops.

Comment: Your teacher is either completely wrong, or you have misreported what he said somehow. This rationale for preferring `for` over `while` simply makes no sense. There may be one, but this isn't it.

Comment: I agree with Kilian. It makes no sense that there should be a difference, as `for (init; test; step) { body }` has a trivial desugaring to `while`: `{init; while (test) { step; body }}`.

Comment: @KilianFoth while over for (not for over while). might be i misinterpreted him but he was quite clear about a while loop being provable and a for loop not (or less)

Comment: For(;;) { cout<<"they're really not that different" <<endl;} . The biggest difference is that for loops let you easily keep a variable (i) at the scope of the loop.

Comment: This is one of the best illustrations of [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) mentality that I have come across in recent times.

Comment: @MikeNakis on the contrary. A cargo culter wouldn't ask the question, just perpetuating myths. Perhaps even punishing others for not "adhering to the rule".

Comment: @sehe I am not referring to Vincent Advocaat as the cargo cult follower;  I am referring to his teacher.

Comment: @MikeNakis I don't know whether we have enough information to assess the mentaility of the teacher.

Comment: It is a fairly good teacher, but this is the only odd thing I've heard him say so far. it sounded plausible, that while loops could somehow be more reliable than for loops. at least that's what it boils down to i think.

Comment: In my opinion there is no difference but someone (like your teacher) can say that there is syntax complexity like:
>For loop requires three arguments and while loop requires just one condition , so there is greater chances of mistakes in for loop than while loop. I know this is weird but it can be explained like that if someone really want to enjoy :)

Comment: It does not boil down to that.  That's someone's impression, and it is a false impression.  Technically, `for` loops are equivalent to `while` loops, and in practice, you should never use a `while` loop there where a `for` loop could be used instead.

Comment: The funny thing about the "all loops must have a fixed upper bound" rule is that `for` works more naturally for it, since you'll generally have some variable dedicated to terminating the loop.

Comment: @Doval exactly!

Comment: This is the problem with education. Why didn't you ask your teacher?+

Comment: @JeffO Because it only later came to me.

Comment: It should also be noted that in order for it to be "trivially possible" for a checking tool to "statically prove" ***anything*** about a piece of code, then we can only be talking about trivial code. Trivial code might be necessary for life-critical or multi-billion-dollar-mission-critical applications, but it constitutes an infinitesimally small fraction of all code written today, so developing the skill to write trivial code does not have very good career prospects.

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/41645/755

Comment: I always thought of a `for` loop as being equivalent to a particular way of writing a `while` loop. Syntactical sugar. It doesn't change what the loop does, but it makes the physical act of writing and reading the loop easier.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat I don't see why. I mean, it's pretty trivial to write a routine that converts a `for` loop into a `while` loop, right? So, assuming we had some proof of an algorithm that depended on there being a `while` loop there, then that's no problem, because we can also prove that the `for` loop (preferred by the professional programmer) is equivalent to the `while` loop (preferred by your prof)

Comment: If you can prove that a while-loop terminates, you'd become a millionaire; `while(non-trivial zero of zeta function not found) { search next interval ;}`

Comment: `do-while` loops are looked down upon. In a `while` loop the conditional expression is a precondition for the body and the negative of the loop postcondition. `do-while` is much more complicated to derive the conditions. You may as well use `while` even if you expect to always loop at least once.

Comment: My _preference_ is to use **for** when you know in advance the length, and **while** when you don't know the length in advance, eg. Processing a file or string provided by the user.  However this is just a guide, you can use **while( i++ < length )** instead of a **for** loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**In a nutshell**: *What your teacher probably meant is that the semantics of `while` is pretty much the same in most languages, while the semantics of `for` may change considerably (see discussion below). Hence, abstract language independent proof are more reliable with a `while`, but one should be careful that a proof with a `for` loop may not match the semantics of the `for` loop in many languages.*

Your question is not precise enough (though that may not be your
fault).

The point is that, afaik, there is no official, ISO supported
standard, or otherwise officially accepted reference definition of
`for` and `while` loops. The definition depends on the programming
language.

Hence you cannot make any general statement regarding their
equivalence before you have defined precisely what each can do. I
adress that more precisely, since it is one of the main argument used
in other answers (and the discussion will be useful in what follows).

### On intertranslatability of `for` and `while` loops

**Summary**: *it depends on the programming language, but is always
possible a long as you can have one infinite loop and a way to get out
of it.*

But you can make such a statement for a specific programming language,
and the answer will depend on the features fo the language.

That also means that there is no general proof, but only one for each
programming language.

One thing that is generally true is that a `while` loop can generally
mimic a `for` loop, because the while loop can do the exit condition
testing of the for loop, doing the initialisation of the control
variable with an assignment before entering the loop, and doing the
incrementation at the end of the loop body, so that

```
for i from 1 by 2 to 10 do { xxx }
```

becomes

```
i=1
while i≤11 do { xxx; i←i+2 }
```

This more or less works for most languages, but it is not as obvious as
it seem, and there may be many "details" to worry about.

For example, in many languages, the `for` loop evaluates it 3
arguments (initial value, increment, and final value) as [strict
arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), evaluated once before entering the loop, while others will
take then as [thunk arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation#Implementation) to be reevaluated at each turn, or
possibly as [lazy argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) to be evaluated only when first needed.

Another point may be that the increment variable may be local to the
`for` loop, or have to be a local variable of the function where the
loop appears.

Depending on such issues, the translation of a `for` to a `while` may
vary widely, though it is usually possible to achieve it.

The same holds for the converse, thranslating a `while` into a `for` loop.

Th first problem is that a `while` loop will always reevaluate the
exit condition at each turn. But some `for` loops do not provide for a
condition that is reevaluated at each turn, other than comparison of
the control variable with some fixed value computed on loop entry.
Then the translation is not possible unless there is some other mean
to jump out of the loop on some arbitrary conditions.

That is achievable with various devices, usually starting with a
conditional statement testing the condition, followed by an a jump out
implemented, as available, by a loop exit statement, a return
statement (after encapsulating the loop in a function), a goto
statement or an exception raising.

In other words, it is again very dependent on languages, and possibly
on subtle features of languages.

This say, as [answered by @milleniumbug](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279716/provability-of-while-loop-vs-for-loop/279731#279731), the intertranslation is easy
in the language C, because a `for` lopp is essentially a `while` loop
plus some extra for an incremented control variable.

But this does not necessarily apply to other languages, and most
likely not in the same way.

This being said, programming languages are usually supposed to have
Turing power with only one of these loops, since all you need for it
is one infinite loop. So, as long as you have some way of looping for
ever, and possibly deciding to stop, you are pretty sure you can mimic
any other construct ... but not necessarily easily.

### Regarding proofs

**Summary**: *There is no reason known to me to assert that proofs should be significantly harder with one or the other (unless some weird feature of the language).*

There is probably a misunderstanding, or your teacher had his mind on
something else.

Formals semantics can be defined for the various kinds of loops
defined in programming languages, and then used for proving
properties.

It may be, again depending on the language, that conducting formal
proofs regarding programs may be more complex in some cases. But that
depends on the language.

I cannot imagine a reason why proofs should be significantly harder with one construct more than with the other. The `for` loop may be more complex since it can offer, as in C, all that is done with a `while` plus other things. But if you did it with a `while`, you would have to add the extras in some other form.

I could use the formal general argument of intertranslatability, as long as there is the possibility for a single infinite loop. I will however refrain from doing that, as the constructions involved are nothing you want to deal with in a proof, and it would clearly be an unfair statement, at least in practice.

Following the above discussion, however, we have seen that the difficulties for intertranslatability come from the great variability of the `for` loop from language to language. Hence the following conclusion which is probably the right answer:

One possibility to understand your teacher's statement is that the semantics of the `while` loop is pretty much the same in all programming languages, while the syntax and semantics of the `for` loop can vary significantly from language to language. Hence, **it is possible to make general "abstract" proofs with `while` loops that have language independent semantics to a good extent, while this is not possible for the `for` loop that has syntax and semantics changing too much from language to language.** But this does not apply within a given language, when the semantics of both are precisely defined.

My best suggestion is that you should ask your teacher what he precisely meant, and whether he can give you an example. Misphrasing or misunderstanding is a common event.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat Well, the site is for all users, no just the Original Poster of the question. That is why I did it. I also flagged my own answer for the moderator to stop it if improper. Actually it was an interesting question, and it took me some time to reach my conclusion ... hoping it is the right one. Let us know if you find out.

Comment: I only just noticed the edit you made an hour ago adding what you state in your answer here, this is indeed the best possible answer to my question and I thank you for it. What moderator attention is concerned, it is more my fault for creating a duplicate amongst multiple SE sites. So for that I see no reason to delete this answer, if anything should be delted it would have to be the 2nd question I asked, but since your answer there is well formulated and explains the statement made here in depth i do not think it wise to remove either one. unless you add the information to this question.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat Do you have any idea why this was just downvoted. I am curious.

Comment: I have no idea, strange things happen, always fun when people don't explain any reasons for this.

Comment: Happened again: 1 up + 1 down. What bothers me is that it is hurting
the site more than myself. I try to write complete answers that help
people. If it is at fault, it would be wiser to comment to give me an
opportunity to correct. If it is some other reason, it just reduces
attractiveness of an answer that might be useful, at the site expense.
I am wondering whether replacing with the extended answer, or removing the
disclaimer at the end, has anything to do with it. But the moderator
seemed ok with the situation.

Comment: As a moderator I like your answer and I learned something from reading it.  It is a good answer

Answer (score 12):

In the C language you can rewrite every `for` loop to an equivalent `while` loop and vice versa.

`while -> for` transformation:

Rewrite

```c
while(condition) { instructions; }
```

to

```c
for(; condition; ) { instructions; }
```

`for -> while` transformation:

This is slightly more complicated, especially if you have `continue` statement in your loop.

Rewrite:

```c
for(init; condition; next) { instructions; }
```

to:

```c
{
    init;
    while(condition)
    {
        instructions;
    next_label:
        next;
    }
}
```

but replace every `continue;` statement with `goto next_label;` statement. If `condition` is a null instruction, replace it with `true`.

As you can see, in C language neither is more "provable" (whatever that means) than the other, since even if one of the loop was, you could rewrite it in terms of another loop.

Now, there exist other languages where this `while <-> for` equivalency doesn't exist. For example, in Pascal, you can assume more about the `for` loop. This means that you can't express every concept when writing a `for` loop, but you can prove more about the flow of the code:

```
for i:=1 to n do
    instructions;
```

Here, the `n` is saved at the beginning of the loop, so changes to `n` don't make any influence on iteration count, and you can't modify `i` in the body of the loop. This means you can trivially prove this loop will eventually end (as `n` is finite, and you can't modify `i`).

Comment: Rewriting some "for" loops as "while" loops would require code duplication, adding flags, or adding `goto`.  If one adds flags, all other loops can be emulated using a single "while(1)..." around a function which runs until a "return"; if one adds "goto", all other loops can be emulated using that.

Comment: Thanks for proving my point. Copy-pasting the code fragment A doesn't change my ability to reason about it.

Comment: Indeed, copy/paste doesn't change one's ability to reason about code, but it is IMHO an important reason not to regard "for" as a superfluous language construct, since one of the design goals of a good programming language should be to minimize the *need* for copy/paste.

Answer (score 7):

In [Floyd-Hoare logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Hoare_logic), the most common formal system for reasoning about the correctness of computer programs, there is the **while rule**.

In words, if you have a *guard clause* (the expression in brackets in the `while()`), a *variant function* (an expression with discrete values that can be shown to decrease monotonically each time the loop runs, and always be positive), and a *loop invariant* (a logic statement that is always true before and after every time the loop runs), you can prove that the while loop will finish (because the variant function can't keep decreasing) and that eventually the guard clause will be false and the loop invariant be true.

Floyd-Hoare logic doesn't have rules for `for` loops or whatever constructs actual languages may have.

However, as other answers explain, for loops can always be written in terms of while loops. That means that they can be reasoned about, it just takes a little more work.

If your teacher had courses at university where he had to provide correctness proofs of his programs, he probably wrote programs using only while loops. I know I did. And once you are used to thinking in terms of guards and variant functions and loop invariants, they seem very natural. Overusing while loops is a habit you see with CS graduates, I had to learn to stop doing that in my first months as a professional developer.

Somewhere down the line, your teacher misremembered all this as "good programmers use while loops", whereas what really happens is more like "some CS graduates turn their correctness proof habits into practical programming habits".

Comment: This seems to be quite consistent with my own assessment, though based on a different view. Floyd-Hoare logic had no reason to consider the `for` loop, which has no fixed definition and is more complex, without being formally necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in some sense, the exact opposite is true.

A language with only `for`-loops is not Turing-complete, it can only compute the primitive-recursive functions, not all Turing-computable functions. Since all computation in a language with only `for`-loops always terminates, the Halting Problem and all the other Decidability Problems based upon it, simply don't arise, so it is possible to mechanically decide many more static properties of programs than in a language with `while`-loops.

OTOH, a language with only natural numbers, a single variable, and `while`-loops *is* Turing-complete, and so it is not possible to decide even the simplest of properties: will this program return a result?

Comment: A `for`-only language can produce `while`-equivalent behavior  by decrementing the loop variable (assuming the language allows it) during iterations which aren't supposed to result in a termination.  (E.g., `for n in 1 to 2 { if condition then n := n-1 }`)

Comment: There are many ways in which a for loop can be made to loop for ever,
depending of course on its definition in the language at hand. And
one infinite loop is enough for Turing completeness.

Comment: @babou: The most common interpretation of a for loop is a loop that iterates over a finite range or collection. Of course, in many languages you can hack a for loop to behave like a while loop, but I think that's not what Jörg had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that in reality, there is no difference .Your question is irrelevant.
May be your teacher might have meant to use while-loop when no. of iterations is not known beforehand.In many cases we need to use a while loop to extract digits of a no. when the user enters the no. which can be of any length. Technically speaking, the similarity between for & while loop is that both are entry-controlled loops wherein the (test-expression/condition) is evaluted before entering into the loop body.This is the distinction between while & do-while loops.

Answer (score -1):

It likely comes from early C programming where, by todays norms, loops were widely abused and misused, especially the conditional being modified. As programmers started to understand the effect certain programming styles had, the abuse and misuse of loop conditionals fell out of favor, and  the statement, while (arguably) once valid, no longer holds any truth.

The statement holds absolutely no truth if you look solely at the language definition and syntax and ignore how it was being used.

The statement itself does however offer a valuable lesson to anyone who wants to understand it, its history and why its no longer considered true. - Whats the expression about learning, mistakes and repeating them.....

Answer (score -10):

Your teacher is correct!

The reason is the following is valid C

```
for (int x = 1 ; x < 20 ; x++ ) {
   x = x + 9;
}
```

You cannot guarantee the condition variables have not been tampered with!

Comment: How does that make `while` loops fare better here?

Comment: Oh yeah? Whereas, with `while` loops you can actually guarantee that the condition variable has *not* been tampered with?  In fact, tampering with the condition variable is the only way to break out of a `while` loop!  I usually refrain from downvoting stuff, but for this answer, I shall make an exception.

Comment: James could you perhaps elaborate why this is less of an issue for while loops, you might be on to something however people seem to disagree for a lac of counter evidence in the case of while loops

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat I'd say that with a while loop you *expect* the condition variable to be tampered with in some way, whereas a for loop you expect it to be changed only in the step part of the for loop construct itself. This [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) is more important than many realise in programming.

Comment: @gbjbaanb true, but as far as the question is concerned, it is a far cry from principle of least astonishment to provability.

Comment: On the contrary, the code you've written proves that there's a guarantee your condition variables WILL be tampered with. I don't understand this answer.